# How is race condition caused when || operator is used instead of && within the std::atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, race-condition, stdatomic

There is a task to make 3 threads execute always in a specific order like so:

```
zero  // prints 0s only
odd   // prints odd numbers    
even  // prints even numbers
```

each of the functions (zero, even, odd) are passed to 3 threads respectively, so the output should be:

```
0102     for n = 2
010203   for n = 3
01020304 for n = 4
and so on
```

In code:

```
class ZeroEvenOdd {
    private:
        int n;
        std::atomic<int> turn{0};
        bool flag = false;

    public:
        ZeroEvenOdd(int n) {
            this->n = n;
        }

        void zero(std::function<void(int)> printNumber) {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < n) {
                while (turn > 0) {// 1 or 2
                    std::this_thread::yield();
                }
                printNumber(0);
                turn = !flag ? 1 : 2;
                flag = !flag;
                ++i;
            }
        }

        void even(std::function<void(int)> printNumber) {
            int i = 2;
            while (i <= n) {
                while (turn < 2) {// 0 or 1
                    std::this_thread::yield();
                }
                printNumber(i);
                turn = 0;
                i += 2;
            }
        }

        void odd(std::function<void(int)> printNumber) {
            int i = 1;
            while (i <= n) {
                //while (turn <= 2 && turn != 1) {// 0 or 2 // how does this expression eliminate the race ???
                while (turn == 0 || turn == 2) { // this causes race condition
                    std::this_thread::yield();
                }
                printNumber(i);
                turn = 0;
                i += 2;
            }
        }
    };
```

Lets look at function `odd`:

In the inner while loop I need to check if `turn` is 0 or 2:

If I the check this way:  `while (turn == 0 || turn == 2) {...}` the race condition appears with a wrong and not complete output.

```
for n = 24
it might be:
010203040506709080110100130120150140170160190180210200230220...(waiting)
```

We see here that after `6` `7` is printed which is wrong...

But if I check this way `while (turn <= 2 && turn != 1) {...}` no races appears and output is correct always.

Analogous races appear for other functions `zero` and `even` when their inner while loops are changed to use `||` operator.

I know that combining atomic operations in expression may not necessarily make the whole expression atomic, but I just can't get my head around what scenario can cause race condition with this check `while (turn == 0 || turn == 2) {...}` ???

**Update**

Full code example to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <functional>

class ZeroEvenOdd {
    private:
        int n;
        std::atomic<int> turn{0};
        bool flag = false;

    public:
        ZeroEvenOdd(int n) {
            this->n = n;
        }

        void zero(std::function<void(int)> printNumber) {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < n) {
                while (turn > 0) {// 1 or 2
                    std::this_thread::yield();
                }
                printNumber(0);
                turn = !flag ? 1 : 2;
                flag = !flag;
                ++i;
            }
        }

        void even(std::function<void(int)> printNumber) {
            int i = 2;
            while (i <= n) {
                while (turn < 2) {// 0 or 1
                    std::this_thread::yield();
                }
                printNumber(i);
                turn = 0;
                i += 2;
            }
        }

        void odd(std::function<void(int)> printNumber) {
            int i = 1;
            while (i <= n) {
                //while (turn <= 2 && turn != 1) {// 0 or 2 // how does this expression eliminate the race ???
                while (turn == 0 || turn == 2) { // this causes race condition
                    std::this_thread::yield();
                }
                printNumber(i);
                turn = 0;
                i += 2;
            }
        }
    };  

    int main() {
        int n = 24;
        std::function<void(int)> printNum = [](int x) {
            std::cout << x << std::flush;
        };
        ZeroEvenOdd zeroEvenOdd(n);
        std::thread t1(&ZeroEvenOdd::zero, &zeroEvenOdd, printNum);
        std::thread t2(&ZeroEvenOdd::even, &zeroEvenOdd, printNum);
        std::thread t3(&ZeroEvenOdd::odd,  &zeroEvenOdd, printNum);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        return 0;
    }
```

command to compile:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -fsanitize=thread -pthread test.cpp -o test
```

Comment: It probably have to do with the [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for the logical operators. For the `&&` operator, if the left-hand side is `false` then the right-hand side won't be evaluated. For `||` it's the opposite, if the left-hand side is `false` the right-hand side *must* be evaluated.

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve] (including a simple caller that passes `atoi(argv[1])` or something) so I can try it easily on my desktop?  Also consider simplifying the outer loop to `while(i<=n) {`.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah sure

Comment: And BTW, I don't see an obvious problem with this, but IDK why you'd want to do 2 separate accesses to the atomic variable instead of loading it into a temporary.  Or more simply, `while( !(turn&1) )` to wait for `turn` to be odd.  Or `while( turn != 1 )`.  Also, `flag` doesn't need to be a class member; only `zero()` uses it so it could be a local var in that function.

Comment: Re, "...make 3 threads execute...in a specific order." FYI, that is a classic BAD homework assignment. It's good that you are learning how to coordinate the activity of different threads, but the entire point of using threads is to allow things to happen _concurrently_ (i.e., in no particular order.)  In any _real_ program, if it is important for certain things to happen in a certain order, those things should all be done in the same thread.

Comment: @SolomonSlow If the individual operations were very expensive then this would still make sense. Yes, there might be synchronisation overhead, but it can still easily be faster than single-threaded operation.

Comment: `std::this_thread::yield()` is a bad choice for thread synchronization. Try using `condition_variable` instead

Comment: @rustyx First easy solution was using `conditon_variable` and was like 2-3 times slower than this...

Comment: @SolomonSlow its not homework assignment at all, but a problem from certain resource.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, I'm talking about a sequence of _events_. If it's important for the program to call function B every time function A returns, then there should be one thread that executes the statements, `A(...);` and `B(...);` in that order. Maybe it makes sense for function B to send a message to some other thread, or maybe it makes sense for function B to submit a background task to a thread pool. I don't mean to rule out those possibilities, but whatever B does, if it's important for it to happen immediately after a call to function A, then it should be done in the same thread that called A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those like me who couldn't glean it immediately from the explanation/code, here is a quick summary:

`zero` can only leave the inner while loop if `turn == 0`. It then sets `turn` to either `1` or `2`.

`even` can only leave the inner while loop if `turn == 2`. It then sets `turn` to `0`.

The intention is that `odd` can only leave the inner while loop if `turn == 1` (it then sets `turn` to `0`.), but this is not implemented correctly.

Since the conditions for leaving the spin loops are (supposed to be) mutually exclusive, no more than one thread should be outside its own spin loop at a given time, so no concurrent modifications should be possible (and the program should then be race-free).

---

The problem is that `turn == 0 || turn == 2` is not atomic. The following can happen:

1. `zero` completes one iteration and sets `turn = 2`.
2. `odd` checks `turn == 0`, which is false.
3. Meanwhile, `even` also sees `turn == 2`, exits the spin loop, completes an iteration and sets `turn = 0`.
4. `odd` now checks the right side of the `||` operator: `turn == 2`, which is false.
5. **`odd` leaves its spin loop (even though `turn == 0`!)** which is of course unintended and leads to a race between zero and odd.

In short, the problem is that the left hand side of `||` might be false but become true by the time the right hand side is evaluated. At no point above was the entire `turn == 0 || turn == 2` equal to `false` if evaluated atomically, but since it is not atomic you got a "mix" of `false || true` and `true || false` (namely `false || false`).

The expression `turn <= 2 && turn != 1` does not have this problem as the first condition is always `true`, and the second condition is the check you really want.

---

In the general case, **the solution is to read the atomic once**, into a local tmp, and check that.  That's better for performance because it allows the compiler to optimize your conditions together, or optimize together whatever you're going to do.

```
    while (true) {
        int t = turn;
        if (!(t == 0 || t == 2)) break;
        yield();
    }
```

Or perhaps hack that into one line with a comma operator.  Comma is a "sequence point" so you can assign to `t` and then read it.  But this is not very human-readable.

```
    int tmp;
    while (tmp=turn, (tmp == 0 || tmp == 2)) {
        yield();
    }
```

If you actually wanted to wait for `turn` to be odd, you could use `turn % 2 == 0` or

```
    while ( turn&1 == 0 )
        yield();
```

Comment: yeah nice thoughts! Also at point 3 didn't you mean `even` also sees that `turn==2` ?